# Fullfill a mesh shape by another mesh UNITY

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh

I succeed to generate a mesh, but there is some big hole. How to fill it easly?

See here there are 3 mesh I want to close with other mesh to add texture/material on .

Is there a easy way to generate it at runtime ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: it is not quite clear what you are asking. Do you have meshes that combined cover up the wole surface, or do you still have holes after all models are in place?

Comment: Hi @zambari, actually it's one gameObject with one mesh, I generate it at runtime from a poligyonCollider2D paths points . But I doesn't write the script to fill these hole, I don't know how to do it.
I add a picture, do you understand what I want to do now ? (thanks for help)

Comment: Another solution would be to use the polygonCollider, which fit perfectly , but I don't know how to convert a polygonCollider2D to a mesh ... see the picture I add on my first post @zambari

Comment: you seem to have all the parts, I am still not sure what is it that you are trying to do and why

Comment: The white part you see is actually a sprite not a mesh. I want that shape but with a mesh

Comment: if you have the points (you do) you can triangulate or just try to get mesh directly https://answers.unity.com/questions/671208/how-to-convert-sprite-to-mesh-or-to-a-polygon-.html